# Weird behaviour on UILabel sometimes not adapting to it's content

Tags: objective-c

I parse some json data and I populate some UILabels created programmatically, this is the code:

```
    pTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(detailsView.frame.origin.x -10, pImage.frame.origin.y + pImage.frame.size.height + 15, detailsView.frame.size.width - 25, 30)];
    pTitle.textColor = [UIColor lowBlack];
    [pTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0]];
    pTitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    pTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
    [detailsView addSubview:pTitle];
```

The frame is fine, but after I get the callBack and set the downloaded data to the UIlabel sometimes it resizes fine but sometimes every word creates a new line because it seems that the frame gets changed.

The only thing I do after downloading the json data is to set the content to the UILabel and then call:

```
[pTitle sizeToFit];
```

How can I fix this behaviour?

**EDIT:**

I found how to recreate the problem, basically if I download a product with a small name like "Test" the frame of the UILabel gets as big as the word so the next downloaded name won't be displayed larger than the word "Test". Is it caused by the `sizeToFit` method?

Comment: Are you sure you are manipulating the label in the main thread?

Comment: I create the UILabel on the ViewDidLoad and then use sizeToFit everytime I download data

Comment: You said "callback".  Are you sure that callback runs in the main thread?

Comment: Yeah ofc, Btw I found why this is caused, i'm editing my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem:

The solution that works to me was to redeclare the frame then again call the `-sizeToFit` again, something like this:

```
pTitle.frame = CGRectMake(detailsView.frame.origin.x -10, pImage.frame.origin.y + pImage.frame.size.height + 15, detailsView.frame.size.width - 25, 30);
[pTitle sizeToFit];
```

Comment: yeah that's correct! Just red that sizeToFit calculates the size based on the last frame set. Thank you!